# Inno Setup: Ord Function or eqivalent?

Tags: encryption, inno-setup, pascal

I'm using inno setup to "crypt" a password:

```
function XORcrypt(Value,Key: string): string;
var
    p,k,pl,kl: integer;
begin
    {very basic encryption, using bitwise XOR}
    result:=Value;
    pl:=Length(Value);
    kl:=Length(Key);
    if (pl>0) and (kl>0) then
    begin
        p:=1; k:=1;
        while (p<=pl) do
        begin
            Result[p]:=Char(Ord(Value[p]) XOR Ord(Key[k]));
            if k=kl then k:=1 else k:=k+1;
                p:=p+1
        end; {while}
    end; {if}
end; {XORcrypt}
```

inno seems not to know the pascal function **Ord** which returns the ASCII value of a requested character (67 for 'C')

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not `Ord()` it's `Char()` you need to use `Chr()` instead.

```
function XORcrypt(Value,Key: String): String;
var
    p,k,pl,kl: integer;
begin
    {very basic encryption, using bitwise XOR}
    result:=Value;
    pl:=Length(Value);
    kl:=Length(Key);
    if (pl>0) and (kl>0) then
    begin
        p:=1; k:=1;
        while (p<=pl) do
        begin
            Result[p]:=Chr(Ord(Value[p]) XOR Ord(Key[k]));
            if k=kl then k:=1 else k:=k+1;
                p:=p+1
        end; {while}
    end; {if}
end; {XORcrypt}
```